# Event in one template fires function in others templates

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

When there are two or more [sliders](https://github.com/NightCatSama/vue-slider-component) in the same template, and they have `:drag-end="myFunc(flower)"`, events fire on every value change and on all [sliders](https://github.com/NightCatSama/vue-slider-component). So myFunc fires on all [sliders](https://github.com/NightCatSama/vue-slider-component).

```
<template>
<div>
    <div v-for="flower in flowers">
            <slider ref="slider" v-model="flower.value" :drag-end="myFunc(flower)"></slider>
    </div>

    <div v-for="tree in trees">
            <slider ref="slider" v-model="tree.value" :drag-end="myFunc(tree)"></slider>
    </div>
<div>
</template>
<script>
const Slider = require('../controls/slider.vue');

module.exports = {

    methods: {
        myFunc: function (plant) {
            console.log("Plant value", plant.value);
        },
    },
    components: {
        Slider
    },
    mounted: function () {

    },
    data() {
        return { }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Could you try to remove `ref` attribute from both sliders ?

Comment: Doesn't affect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see in documentation, `drag-end` is the event, so then it should be used as event:

```
<div v-for="flower in flowers">
        <slider ref="slider" v-model="flower.value" @drag-end="myFunc(flower)"></slider>
</div>

<div v-for="tree in trees">
        <slider ref="slider" v-model="tree.value" @drag-end="myFunc(tree)"></slider>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You. Gonna study vue.js documentation on this weekend. Again.

Comment: Welcome.Well this was related to `vue-slider-component` library documentation, not directly to Vue.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare a different function for each slider.

```
<template>
<div>
    <div v-for="flower in flowers">
            <slider ref="slider" v-model="flower.value" :drag-end="funcFlower(flower)"></slider>
    </div>

    <div v-for="tree in trees">
            <slider ref="slider" v-model="tree.value" :drag-end="funcTree(tree)"></slider>
    </div>
<div>
</template>
<script>
const Slider = require('../controls/slider.vue');

module.exports = {

    methods: {
        funcFlower: function (plant) {
            console.log("Plant value", plant.value);
        },
        funcTree: function (plant) {
            console.log("Plant value", plant.value);
        },
    },
    components: {
        Slider
    },
    mounted: function () {

    },
    data() {
        return { }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why would that matter ? If that could be true, then Javascript would sucks because you have to repeat yourself all time :) This method is reusable and It accept one parameter, so you can use it as many time you want in current component.